# Server.MapPath problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.mappath

My problem is that I just can't seem to get the actual file of my mapPath in my foreeach loop.

```
foreach (DataRow item in objKat.getProd().Rows)
    {
        ddlImage.Items.Add(new ListItem(Server.MapPath("../img/produkter/"), item["fldId"].ToString()));
    }
```

The actual problem is that I don't know what to write after produkter/". Hope any of you can help me. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: If path is "/img/produkter/" use this syntax: "~/img/produkter/"

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you should what you want to do, and not how?

Answer (score 1):

When you using the `MapPath` your path may look look this

```
 Server.MapPath("~/img/produkter/")
```

Read more about [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IS `Produkter` is a `Subfolder` in `img` folder. If it's then your image name is in `item["fldId"].ToString()` then use that..otherwise your `Relative` path of image should be come after `Produkter`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the strings. If you want to go to /somefolder/fileyoudesire.ext, it needs to be //somefolder//fileyoudesire.ext